# Changing port when using netcat

Tags: netcat, nc

The manual instructs to use -p option for entering port. When I tried to use it, 'no port to connect' was displayed. I was connecting to localhost. But the connection went through when `nc localhost 3000` was used instead of `nc localhost -p 3000`. Is it different when connecting to localhost or am I interpreting the manual wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connection has two endpoints.

`nc` binds to some local address and port, this is the local endpoint. The local port can be [allocated automatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) or you can request a specific port, this is what `-p` is for. You may or may not use `-p`.

`nc` tries to connect to some address and port, this is the remote endpoint. By `nc host port` you specify the remote address and port. You must specify the remote port, otherwise the tool doesn't know where to connect to (e.g. `no port to connect`).

In `nc localhost -p 3000` the remote end is at `localhost` but this changes nothing. The tool doesn't care if the address is `localhost` or whatever, it needs to know an address *and a port* to connect to. These are mandatory. You told it the address but not a port to connect to (therefore `no port to connect`). You told it a port to bind to, this is optional.

In `nc localhost 3000` you exactly specify where to connect to. There is no `-p` and the tool binds to some random(-ish) port. This is enough to make the tool work.